# Exibir apenas ícone do link de acordo com tamanho da tela

Tags: css

Em minhas páginas, tenho vários links como o a seguir:

```
<a href="/Home/Index" class="btn-sm btn-success" role="button">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home
</a>
```

Ele mostra um ícone na frente do texto que, quando clicados, redirecionam para um caminho.

Gostaria que, dependendo do tamanho da tela, esse texto aparecesse ou deixasse de aparecer, nesse caso, mantendo apenas o ícone.

Qual a melhor prática para fazer isso via CSS?

Comment: @mediaquerie...

Comment: Sim, sei que existe, ia até comentar, porém como eu faria? Tem como "apagar" o texto do link através do css dentro do @mediaquerie? Não sei qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer...

Comment: Faz um mix de https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries usando a propriedade `display:none`....

Comment: Mas com um display:none ele ocultaria todo o botão do link, não é? Ao invés de só o texto do link.

Comment: Veja, no seu caso não é um botão e sim um link, então você deve estruturar seu html de forma que você possa usar esse tipo de solução, então neste seu caso você poderia envolver o texto com uma tag `span` ou  sei lá qual e aplicar somente no texto...

Comment: Botão que eu quis dizer é em relação ao "formato" dele que conseguimos através do class btn do bootstrap, mas sim, é um link. Obrigado.

Comment: Na minha opinião a melhor prática para seu problema é usar media queries. ai você pode manipular seus elementos de acordo com os tamanhos desejados. dê uma olhada nesse link: https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/ @Rafael

Comment: Rafael sem colocar uma tag no texto do menu acho que vc não vai conseguir. Mas se colocar a tag não for problema, posso fazer um modelinho simples de CSS que já resolve.

Comment: Coloque uma  tag span entre o texto home... e use a media query para ocultar somente a tag span, ai o icone irá permanecer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor prática para modificar o estilo dependendo do tamanho da tela é por [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

Esse CSS oculta o texto e exibe apenas o ícone quando a largura da página é menor ou igual a 768 pixels, como o ícone é branco foi necessário adicionar um *background-color* nele:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .element {
    visibility: hidden; /* Oculta o elemento */
  }
  
  .element i{ /* Seleciona somente o ícone dentro do link */
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    visibility: visible; /* Mostra somente o ícone */
  }
}
</style>
<a href="/Home/Index" class="element btn-sm btn-success" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a>
```